# Electron Forge webpack plugin - not seeing node modules

Tags: macos, node-modules, electron-forge, dmg, webpack-plugin

I have been using the electron-forge webpack plugin to create a packaged bundle. My main process uses node modules. I have followed the webpack plugin documentation and have set up webpack.main.config and webpack.renderer.config according to the provided template. I have included a dmg maker in the forge.config file, and am able to create a dmg file after an 'npm run make'. However, when running the application, the modules in my node_modules folder (eg httpProxy) can't be accessed via a require. Node modules incorporated into node (eg path) can be accessed. Is there something I can add to webpack.main.config that might enable this access? I have specified the @vercel/webpack-asset-relocator-loader and @grumpy/webpack-node-loader (needed this for a .node file).

Here is my webpack.main.config file:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin({ resourceRegExp: /osx-temperature-sensor$/}),
  ],
  /**
   * This is the main entry point for your application, it's the first file
   * that runs in the main process.
   */
  entry: './main.js',
  resolve: {
    modules: ['node_modules'],
    extensions: ['.js']
  },
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  // Put your normal webpack config below here
  module: {
    //rules: require('./webpack.rules'),
    rules: [
      {
        test: /[/\\]node_modules[/\\].+\.(m?js|node)$/,
        parser: { amd: false },
        use: {
          loader: '@vercel/webpack-asset-relocator-loader',
          options: {
            outputAssetBase: 'native_modules',
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.node$/,
        loader: '@grumpy/webpack-node-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
```

Comment: Hi, I am facing a similar issue as well. Were you able to resolve it?